# Automatic login and uploading a file into a web server

Tags: web-scraping

i have a system given to me by a client to upload a file to send money to my clients. the way it works is this. i have to login credentials. the first one i log in to upload a CSV file with the clients phone number and money he needs to withdraw. then the second login is used to approve the file that has been uploaded so that money can be sent to that number.

Am looking into automating the process. Can anyone please help me on this. I have a monday deadline on this i really need ur help. Am offering to pay something small for anyone who offers the solution

Comment: Don't use StackOverflow as a classifieds board. StackOverflow is a learning resource, not a place to outsource your work. And if your deadline is coming up, then you should have planned ahead or asked for a later deadline. Don't expect people to give your question priority just because you're on a deadline (we all have deadlines to meet).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about PHP/Python but in Rails we have [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). Try searching for similar solutions for PHP or Python.

---

Mechanize allows you to replicate the human behavior (though within certain limits). You can define actions which replicate opening the form url, uploading a file(from local machine) and then call the logout url (the url which is called by logout button).

Answer (score 1):

For python [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is also available as **Jagira** mentioned for Rails.
There are some examples on the page.

Comment: Thanks jagira and mpOint i really appreciate. My question would be then how do i upload the file to the system. I can only see someone logging in which functions do i use to upload a file and securely log out from the system